# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible - When training CNN with Keras using image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

ValueError: Shapes... incompatible is a pretty generic bug when using tensors, but in my case it was when training CNN with Keras using `image_dataset_from_directory` method.

Comment: What shape are the images in the dataset, and what shape did you specify for the InputLayer of the CNN?

Comment: @Mark Lavin I'm using the image_size argument of tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory to resize the images, image_size=(150, 150) and in the model definition keras.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to replace 'categorical_crossentropy' by 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' in the compilation statement.

Why? According to image_dataset_from_directory documentation, 'int' is the default label encoding. So, by default, 'image_dataset_from_directory' will create a set of labels for the dataset  as integer that go from 1 to the number of classes in the dataset.

In this case, the model should be compiled with a 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' loss, not 'categorical_crossentropy'.